# TestBed mocking service

Tags: angular, jasmine, testbed

I got component to test with method:

```
     switchDocumentLanguage(lang, formData):any {
        if (lang === this.currentLang) {
          return null;
        }
        if (formData.invalid && this.currentLang === this.appConfig.defaultLanguage ||
          !this.documentFormData.content && this.currentLang === this.appConfig.defaultLanguage) {

          return this.modalService.open(this.setDefaultModal);

        }

        //(2*)
        if (formData.invalid || !this.documentFormData['content']) {
          return this.modalService.open(this.tabSwitchModal).result.then(() => {
            this.fillFormData(lang);
          }, (reason) => {
          });
        } else {
          return this.fillFormData(lang);
        }
      }
```

It falls to condition marked (2*)

In test i use stub class ModalService:

```
    class ModalService {
      open(someArg?: any){
        return {result : Promise.resolve('success')};
      }
    }

    const appConfig =
    {
      defaultLanguage: 'en-US'
    }
```

and my test config  looks like:

```
 describe('document.edit component test', () => {

  let component: DocumentEditComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DocumentEditComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],

      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [DocumentEditComponent],
      providers: [{provide: AppConfig, useValue: appConfig},
        {provide: DocumentsService, useValue: documentsService},
        {provide: NgbModal, useClass: ModalService},
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute},
        {provide: BaThemeSpinner, useValue: loader},
        {provide: PopupResultService, useValue: popupResultService},
      ],
    })
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DocumentEditComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

and here is the test that gives me  error:

```
  it("try to leave custom language with invalid form", async(() => {
      const componentService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NgbModal);

      let spyObj = spyOn(componentService, "open")

      component.documentFormData.content = "some test values";
      component.currentLang = "es-VE";


      fixture.detectChanges();
      component.switchDocumentLanguage("ru-Ru", {invalid: true})
      fixture.detectChanges();

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
    }));
```

Error text :

```
document.edit component test try to leave custom language with invalid form
Failed: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
```

It looks like my stub class "ModalService" doesn't return anything, i tried to place there console.log() but it never appear.
Is anyone has come across with similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not being called because you have a spy on it.

Probably what you could do is, extend the spy with [callThrough()](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E)

```
let spyObj = spyOn(componentService, "open").and.callThrough();
```

EDIT :

You could also do it using [returnValue()](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValue%3C/code%3E)

```
let spyObj = spyOn(componentService, "open").and.returnValue({result : Promise.resolve('success')});
```

In this case `open()` wont be called, instead you will return the same result that is returned by mock Class method. You will not need mock Class too if you use this.

Comment: But i need to know that it was called by component. And if i spy on smth, it will be never called by component?

Comment: I got other case: 

  it("try to leave custom language with invalid form", async(() => {
            const componentService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NgbModal);
        
            let spyObj = spyOn(componentService, "open")
        
            component.switchDocumentLanguage("ru-Ru", {invalid: true})
            fixture.detectChanges();
        
            fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
              fixture.detectChanges();
              expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalled()
            })
          }));

Comment: it goes to "switchDocumentLanguage" second 'if' where not called 'result' of mocked service 'open' method and it works fine, it has detected Spyed object.

Comment: If you donot add `and.callThrough()` to spy, then the `open()` wont be invoked. You can verify the difference.

Comment: Well, you could also do `let spyObj = spyOn(componentService, "open").and.returnValue({result : Promise.resolve('success')});`. In this case `open()` wont be called instead you will return the same result that is returned by mock Class method.